# Using Google Apps script to convert form submissions

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to `Google Apps`, and I'm having much difficulty reformatting my data.

I built a form that outputs into Google Spreadsheet. The form asks 6 questions, and it asks that set of 6 questions 5x. Currently, the output shows 30 columns of data. I want to build a Google Apps Script that can reformat that into a single list of data, so each submission will convert to 5 rows of data that is 6 columns wide instead of 1 row of data that is 30 columns wide.

As an added tweak, Column A shows the date of submission, and I would like it to repeat this for each row of data from that submission. Also, each submission can have up to 5 entries (of 6 pieces of data each), but it can also have just 1,2,3 or 4.

Here is the output I'm working with:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AltfQKymTKF2dGRrMU50ZkU3MGhIUHlvSFdBMDd2MWc&rm=full#gid=0

I think the formula should say something like:

```
Look at Column H
Find first instance where cell is not blank
Copy that and 6 cells over
Paste
Set the original copied cells to blank
i + 1
repeat

then repeat the entire process in Column M
then repeat the entire process in Column T
etc.
```

Please help me if you have ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Data coming from forms are also available as variables when using an "on form submit' trigger, see [doc here about Spreadsheet Form Submit Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events?hl=en)

you should use these variable to build the spreadsheet arrangement you want in a second sheet while leaving the 30 columns one as it is...

The best approach would probably be to build a 2D array with the appropriate data and to write it at once in this sheet (could be in another spreadsheet as well... )

this should be quite easy to setup by pushing data in an array 5 by 5 if the answer is not empty

something like this (not tested)

```
function formSubmit(e) {
  var data = []
  for(n=0;n<5;++n){
    var row = []
    if(e.values[3+n]!=''){  // if first element of serie n is not empty
      for(c=0;c<6;++c){
      row.push(e.values[3+n+c]);// build row n with 6 colums (0 to 5)
        }
    }else{continue}
  data.push(row);// add row n to data  (0 to 4)
}
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1].getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);// write data to sheet #2
}
```

EDIT : I mixed up 5 and 6, I changed the script to handle 5 rows of 6 answers... sorry if you saw first version ;-)

Comment: I understand the concept of storing the form submissions in an Array and pasting those into a new spreadshet. I was able to tie your code to a trigger on form submission, but it gives me the TypeError: Cannot read. After some searching, i think it's because 'value' isn't a standard propertpy. Is there a script library that I should be using?

Thank you for your help here. I'm trying to support a non-profit, and your assistance is invaluable.